# Matlab RANSAC function returns too many parameters and doesn't select inliers correctly

Tags: matlab, data-fitting, ransac

I am trying to use the `ransac` function in matlab to fit a harmonic function to relate between two variables: phi spanning -pi -> pi and theta spanning 0 -> pi. However, while my function has 9 parameters, ransac returns a list of 20 parameters. In addition, when I test the distances of the model's predicition from the actual data using the distance function I defined, I see that it filters out too many data points as outliers, while taking as inliers points which are above the defined threshold.

Here is my code. Note that my data in PointsTP is a nx2 variable with phi (my independent variable) in the second column and theta in the first. [Here is a link to the data in the example including the variables PointsTP and Weight](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13aPKRv15pZvLSdaEM5kDzIthaAFybLft/view?usp=sharing).

```
Weight = (0.7.*RdgPtsCrv./sum(RdgPtsCrv)+0.3.*PointsXYZ(:,3)./sum(PointsXYZ(:,3)));
TPmodel = fit(PointsTP(:,2),PointsTP(:,1),...
    fittype('a1+a2*sin(x)+a3*cos(x)+a4*sin(2*x)+a5*cos(2*x)+a6*sin(3*x)+a7*cos(3*x)+a8*sin(4*x)+a9*cos(4*x)'),...
    'StartPoint',[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],'weights',Weight);
TPfun = @(t) TPmodel(t);
DistFun = @(model, PointsTP) abs(PointsTP(:,1) - TPfun(PointsTP(:,2)));
[ModelPars,Inls] = ransac([PointsTP(:,2),PointsTP(:,1)],TPfun,DistFun,10,0.5,'MaxNumTrials',10000);
```

Running the code I receive the following warning:
Warning: Maximum number of trials reached. Consider increasing the maximum distance or decreasing the desired confidence.

The real problem is the while the function I fit has only nine parameters, ModelPars is a 20X1 variable (with values which make no sense). In addition, when I check the data points selected as inliers, there are many inconsistencies with the maxDistance value of 0.5 given to ransac. If I plot the data points with colors depicting their distance from the fitted model it is clear that there much more points which are below that 0.5 thresholds than are actually selected (filled) as well as selceted points which are much higher than the threshold:

```
dist = DistFun(TPmodel,PointsTP);
fig1 = figure();
ax1=axes();
scatter(PointsTP(:,2),PointsTP(:,1),25,dist,'.');
hold on
scatter(PointsTP(Inls,2),PointsTP(Inls,1),25,dist(Inls),'o','filled');
plot(-pi:2*pi/99:pi,TPfun(-pi:2*pi/99:pi));
```

[image: Datapoints for RANSAC. Colors correspond to distance from fitted model. Inliers selected by RANSAC are filled circles.]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I can't help more without an actual [mcve], but have you tried not making the distance absolute value?

Comment: @AnderBiguri - I'm sorry, added a link to the necessary variables. For your question - yeah, I tried changing the DistFun but it didn't help. I think it must has something to do with the Model variable return by ransac and the way it should be used to evaluate the distance, but I don't know how and can't find any relevant documentation or answers.

Comment: `ransac` returns the parameter array returned by `TPfun`, so if you have too many parameters in that array, your problem is there.

Comment: You should probably use an anonymous function as input to `fit`, rather than the string. See here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html#bto2vuv-11